# Is there a bug in GNU date? (calculating offsets)

Tags: date, offset, gnu

I am trying to group log file entries by week, and using GNU date to find timestamp offsets for comparison against the log entries:

```
$ date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.25

$ today=$(date +%F)
$ ts_sow=$(date -d "$today - $(( $(date -d $today +%u) - 1) days" +%F)
```

This gives the date for Monday of the current week.

```
$ echo $today
2018-11-15
$ echo $ts_sow
2018-11-12
```

Now when I want to go back to the prior week, I can offset from the start of the current week by 7 days...

```
$ ts_sopw=$(date -d "$ts_sow - 7 days" +%F)
$ echo $ts_sopw
2018.11-05
```

But if I try to apply both offsets to the original starting date it gives an incorrect result...

```
$ ts_sopw=$(date -d "$today - $(( $(date -d $today +%u) - 1 - 7 )) days" +$F)
$ echo $ts_sopw
2018-11-11
```

Is this a bug, or is there something more going on here that I am not understanding?

Comment: Shouldn't you __add__ 7 to the number of days to-be subtracted from your current date?

Comment: Hm.  So it was just a maths error that has been confusing me!!

Answer (score 0):

With the *correct* arithmetic, I can get the *correct* result:

```
$ ts_sopw=$(date -d "$today - $(( $(date -d $today +%u) - 1 + 7 )) days" +$F)
$ echo $ts_sopw
2018-11-05
```

**I** was the bug!